# Get element by input text id

Tags: javascript

what is wrong with the code? i have to get the text from the input text box after clicking on submit button, the input text value must be shown in paragraph.

```
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>
<br>
<input id="myList" type="text">
<input type="button" value="Try it" onclick="myFunction()"></button>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
var x = document.getElementById("myList");
var txt = "Welcome ";
for (var i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{
txt = txt + x.elements[i].id + "br";
 }
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=txt;
}
</script>

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah why the for loop???

Comment: No problem! we learn from mistakes.

Comment: yep! but i am just learning now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Check here a demo](http://jsbin.com/ICUSoQO/3/)

Check here no need to loop all the elements

You just need a id of the element so why are you looping it ?

[Here is the source code of it](http://jsbin.com/ICUSoQO/3/edit)

This is the javascript code looks like

```
function myFunction()
{
var x = document.getElementById("myList");
var txt = "Welcome ";

txt = txt + x.value + "br";

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=txt;
}
```

You want a value from the element so you have to take a value you can see in the functiont 
**x.value** so it will ***retrive the value from the element*** and then your function will work i hope this will help you

Comment: please post the relevant code here; we don't want to access external websites to read answers; also, can you add some explanation?

Comment: `x.value` he want value from it

Comment: can you add that explanation into the answer, please?

Comment: Means what type of explanation?

Comment: @JanDvorak added explanation

Comment: looks good now (except for formatting; please remove the code block formatting for what isn't code)

Comment: hmmm i think you should be moderator :D :D

Answer (score 4):

You would want to use this code

```
document.getElementById('myList').value;
```

it will grab the value from the input box element.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to fix it:

**[1]** Change `x.length` to `x.value.length` and `x.elements` to `x.value.elements`

[The fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q75PP/1/)

**[2]** Change `var x = document.getElementById("myList");` to `var x = document.getElementById("myList").value;`

[And the fiddle, why not?](http://jsfiddle.net/q75PP/)

A text box has no property length, so I think you are referencing to its text?  That's what this fix will do.  (Also, it's better practice to use method 2.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to take the "myList" id's value and then assign it to innerHTML of

tag which could be done as follows :

```
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<br>
<form>
<input id="myList" type="text">
<input type="button" value="Try it" onclick="myFunction()"/>
</form>
<script>
function myFunction()
{

 var txt = "Welcome";
 var x = document.getElementById("myList").value;
 txt = txt +" "+x;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=txt;
}
</script>

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Some explanation would be nice; it's hard to learn from code only, and Stack Overflow is not to hand out code.

Comment: Sorry @JanDvorak ....@user3148414 you have to just take the value from the id and assign it to innerhtml of <p> tag. :)

Comment: I mean, in the answer, not as a comment. Please note the [edit] link below your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>
<br>
<input id="myList" type="text">
<input type="button" value="Try it" onclick="myFunction()">
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("myList").value;
        alert(x);
        var txt = "Welcome ";
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            txt = txt + x.charAt(i) + "<br />";
        }
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
    }
</script>

</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

loop??? I didn't understand its very simple try this.

```
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p><br>
<input id="myList" type="text">
<input type="button" value="Try it" onclick="myFunction()">
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("myList");
        var txt = "Welcome " + x.value;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

OR

```
        var x = document.getElementById("myList").value;
        var txt = "Welcome " + x;
```